# Back reference to the matched text in awk

Tags: awk

I need to escape some characters from my awk (GNU Awk 4.2.0) input - `{` with `\{`, `[` with `\[` and `|` with `\|`. I accomplished that with three `gsub` calls:

```
for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
    gsub(/{/, "\\{", $i)
    gsub(/\[/, "\\[", $i)
    gsub(/\|/, "\\|", $i)
}
```

How can I combine those three calls into one? Something like

```
gsub(/([{[|])/, "\\\1", $i)
```

Comment: Which `awk` are you using?

Comment: The one from cygwin. Looks like it is gawk: 

    $ awk -V

    GNU Awk 4.2.0, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.6-p1, GNU MP 6.1.2)

Answer (score 8):

You [can use `&` in the replacement to refer to the matched text](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[[{|]/, "\\\\&", $0); print}' <<<"abc { | [ def"
abc \{ \| \[ def
```

That's just a regular `[...]` character class with `[`, `|`, and `{` in it in the pattern, and a sufficiently-escaped backslash followed by `&` in the replacement. You do need all of them.

---

For more complex patterns [gawk has a `gensub` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-gensub_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029-1) that lets you make references to part of the text, like `\\1`, but you don't need that here. All POSIX-compatible `awk`s support the `&` behaviour for including the entire matched substring in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

OP might've wanted to protect `$1` from these, so perhaps :

```
echo; 
( 
  mawk '{ gsub(/[[{|]/, "\\\\&", $0); print}'    <<<"a[b{c { | [ def";

  mawk '$(((__=$!_)gsub("[[{|]","\\\\&"))~_)=__' <<<"a[b{c { | [ def" \

) | gcat -n | lgp3 


 1  a\[b\{c \{ \| \[ def

 2  a[b{c \{ \| \[ def
```

So instead of having to loop everything from `$2 to $NF`, simply save an original copy of `$1`, have `gsub()` process through the entire row, then place it back,

with the added bonus of placing the original copy of `$1` back into first field will act as if one has done `$1=$1`, ensuring the row will print regardless of whether any substitutes have been made or not.